# ¿Por qué sonarqube dice que mi método en Java no esta totalmente cubierto por la prueba unitaria?

Tags: java, junit, junit-5, mockito, sonarqube

Tengo un servio en Java que consulta a una Bd y me regresa una lista, dentro de mi servicio llamo al método **validacionCampos()** de mi clase Util la cual valida que si ciertos campos de la lista que regresa el servicio  vienen null o con valor 0, les setee el valor 0.000, y el punto es que arme unos testcase para validar todo el metodo del service y de la clase util, pero la herramienta de sonarqube me indica que la cobertura no esta totalmente cubierta y marca las lineas del if de la clase util.

Que esta mal en mis testcase? o como debo de modificarlos para que se cubra todo el codigo tanto del service como de la clase util,
lo que hago es crear un objeto de mi entidad y setearle el null y el 0, para que la prueba cubra esa parte de la clase util pero al parecer no funciona del todo, esta bien inyectar con @Mock mi repository o debe de ser mi clase del ServiceImpl?

Clase ServiceImpl

```
 @Override
public ResponseEntity<?> consultarReportes(Integer fechaInicio, Integer fechaFin) throws Exception {
    Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
    List<EntityDa> consultarReporte = new ArrayList<EntityDa>();
    try {
        consultarReporte = bitacoraRepository
                .consultarBitacoras(fechaInicio, fechaFin);
        reporteUtil.validacionCampos(consultarReporte);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("An error ocurred looking for Entity Data");
        response.put("success", false);
        response.put("error", e.getMessage());
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>>(response, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
    response.put("success", true);
    response.put("data", consultarReporte);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Clase Util

```
private static final String DECIMAL = "0.0000";

        public List<EntityDa> validacionCampos(List<EntityDa> lista) {
        for (EntityDa details : lista) {
            if (details.getRango() == null || details.getRango().equals("0")) {
                details.setRango(DECIMAL);
            }
            if (details.getPrima() == null || details.getPrima().equals("0")) {
                details.setPrima(DECIMAL);
            }
        }
        return lista;
        }
```

Clase Test

```
        @Mock
        BitacoraRepository bitacoraRepository;
        
        @Test
        void testExitoValidaNullos() throws Exception {
            EntityDa entity = new EntityDa();
            entity.setRango(null);
            entity.setPrima(null);
            
            List<EntityDa> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(entity);
            when(bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("20220112", "20220112")).thenReturn(list);
        }
        
        @Test
        void testExitoValidaVacios() throws Exception {
            EntityDa entity = new EntityDa();
            entity.setRango("0");
            entity.setPrima("0");
            
            List<EntityDa> list = new ArrayList<>();
            list.add(entity);
            when(bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("20220112", "20220112")).thenReturn(list);
        }
```

Comment: Hombre, el mock está bien... pero añadir alguna comprobación al test haría que sirvan de algo y no solo *decoren*. Tal cual tienes los test... no hacen nada. Deberías instanciar el servicio, pasarle el repositorio mockeado y llamar al método del servicio comprobando que los datos devueltos están correctos con "`asserts`"

Comment: @Benito-B como es eso de instanciar el servicio y pasarle el repo mockeado? podrias apoyarme por favor

Answer (score 1):

En la definición de tu método pones `throws Exception`.

Ese es el caso extra que te falta validar

1. Con tu mockito haces que tire una excepción tu mock al ser llamado.

   ```
    when(bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("20220112", "20220112")).thenThrow(MiTipoDeExcepcion.class);
   ```
2. Como usas JUnit5 puedes usar el poderoso assertThrows

   ```
   assertThrows(MiTipoDeExcepcion.class,()->bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("-20220112", "-20220112"));
   ```

Si de casualidad necesitas validar algo especial en la excepción tendrás que hacer las validaciones como se hacían en junit 4.

```
try{
   when(bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("20220112", "20220112")).thenThrow(new MiTipoDeExcepcion("#toymorido"));
   bitacoraRepository.consultarBitacoras("-20220112", "-20220112")
   fail("este método debería lanzar una excepción cuando se cumpla la condición de números negativos usados como fechas");
} catch(MiExcepcion excepcion){
  assertNotNull(excepcion.getMessage());
  assertEquals("#pos me muero",excepcion.getMessage());
}
```

Si te fijas llamamos explícitamente a `fail` para decirle a Junit que algo va mal si la ejecucuión llega hasta ese punto.